# Converting GstVideoFrame to GstBuffer | Gstreamer

Tags: c++11, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I having a **two custom plugin** where the video frame is captures by using the below function.

```
gst_custom_transform_frame_ip (GstVideoFilter * filter, GstVideoFrame * frame)
```

In this **video frame i wanted to add meta data in Tx** side & also wanted to extract the same meta data once i get the frame in Rx side.

Below are the function I am using to add & get the meta data.

```
GstMeta meta = gst_buffer_add_video_crop_meta( GstBuffer * Tx_buffer) // Add the meta data in TX side.


GstMeta meta = gst_buffer_get_video_crop_meta (GstBuffer *Rx_buffer); // Rx side.
```

As you can see both the function are expecting type **GstBuffer buffer instead of GstVideoFrame

Can anyone helps me on how do **i can convert the GstVideoFrame buffer to GstBuffer** & vise versa.
Very new in this environment any input will be highly appreciated
Ref. link https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugin-development/advanced/allocation.html?gi-language=c#gstmeta
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking up on the documentation of `GstVideoFrame` here:

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/video/video-frame.html?gi-language=c

You will see that this structure also has a `buffer` member that holds a `GstBuffer`.

Comment: Yes, it is working fine. But I have one doubt here by mentioning the coordinates it is doing coping on the original image and then  sending to the next element . so I am getting croped image but i wanted full frame from the 1 element + this meta data as a addinal information

Comment: is it possible to get the meta data as a addition information along with this original  frame?

Comment: Well if there is an element interpreting these values and acts accordingly (a render I guess).. The info itself should not modifiy the buffer.

Comment: At TX side:  meta =  gst_buffer_add_video_crop_meta (frame->buffer); // add the meta data information.    meta->x=10;  // add coordinates information..                                                                         At RX side.  meta = gst_buffer_get_video_crop_meta (frame->buffer);                         if (meta) {
/* render frame with cropping */
_render_frame_cropped (buffer, meta->x, meta->y, meta->width, meta->height);
}

Comment: If I using the above function then the TX side is seding the croped frame data as per the coordinates I guess. would you please suggest what API I can use so that I should receive original frame along with meta data. (coordinates) without doing and croping on it.

Comment: You can always add your custom metadata structure. Note that in either case your way of transmission must handle that as well (since it is not clear how you transmit)

Comment: Following steps I am following to create the custom plugin.  ./ git clone https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-bad.git.  
../gst-plugins-bad/tools/gst-element-maker 1-element videofilter

and then I just added the functions to add the meta data as shown below.
static GstFlowReturn
gst_vaifacedetect_transform_frame_ip (GstVideoFilter * filter, GstVideoFrame * frame) 
{
  // do_process
  meta =  gst_buffer_add_video_crop_meta (frame->buffer);
  meta->x = 10;
  meta->y = 20;
  GST_DEBUG_OBJECT (vaifacedetect, "transform_frame_ip");
  return GST_FLOW_OK;
}

Comment: can u please share me some referance code to add the custom meta data so that I can send this meta along with GstVideoFrame frame without croping it.

very new to this environment. Any input will be highly appropriated.

Comment: Maybe check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40630098/there-is-a-standard-template-of-gstreamer-metadata-already-defined

Comment: Hii Florian Z, I have tried the solution mentioned in the link above.

Comment: it is working fine if am doing the meta data reading and writing  in the same custom plugin-1. But I wanted to send meta data of custom-plugin-1 to custom plugin-2.  and then from the plugin-2 I wanted to read it back

Comment: for the more detail on the same could you please look at the forum mentioned below.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63789096/meta-data-sharing-between-two-custom-plugins