# Meta data sharing between two custom plugins

Tags: plugins, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I have successfully implemented the meta data API by following the below reference link.

```
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugin-d 
evelopment/advanced/allocation.html?gi-language=c#implementing-new- 
gstmeta
```

So far I have done the meta data **writing and reading back from the same custom plugin-1** as shown below.

### **custom-plugin_1:**

```
gst_custom-plugin-1_transform_frame_ip (GstVideoFilter * filter, GstVideoFrame * frame){

api_id =  my_example_meta_api_get_type();
auto m =  gst_buffer_add_my_example_meta(frame->buffer, 40 , "check"); // write data to buffer
MyExampleMeta* meta= (MyExampleMeta*) gst_buffer_get_meta(frame->buffer,api_id); // read it back to conform it 
std::cout << "Reading back: " << meta->name << meta->age <<  std::endl; 

}
```

By reading back the meta data from the **GstVideoFrame buffer** I **validated that the meta data is successfully written to the video frame** which **will pass to the next custom-plugin-2** as shown in below.

```
src->custom_1--->custom_2---->display
    | meta    |
    |---------|
```

### **Problem**

```
Encountring the below error when I am trying to get back the meta data from the second custom plugin-2

 (gst-launch-1.0:2743): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 02:54:07.460: gst_buffer_get_meta: assertion 'api != 0' failed
```

### **Custom-plugin_2

```
 gst_custom-plugin-2_transform_frame_ip (GstVideoFilter * filter, GstVideoFrame * frame){    

 api_id =  my_example_meta_api_get_type();
 MyExampleMeta* meta =(MyExampleMeta*)gst_buffer_get_meta(frame->buffer,api_id);
 }

GType
    my_example_meta_api_get_type (void) // same as custom-plugin-1
    {
    static volatile GType type;
    static const gchar *tags[] = { "foo", "bar", NULL };

    if (g_once_init_enter (&type)) {
    GType _type = gst_meta_api_type_register ("MyExampleMetaAPI", tags);
    g_once_init_leave (&type, _type);
    }
    return type;
}
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong or can anyone guide me on how do I can **read back this meta data which I am integrated to the GstVideoFrame frame** in the 1-custom plugin?

Comment: By reading some forums I am to know that I needs to create a shared library in order to share the metadata across the element. anyone could elaborate to  me how do i can do this?                               http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Having-issues-using-GstMeta-in-GStreamer-1-0-5-td4658241.html#a4658271

Comment: Yes it needs to be a shared library and both plugins must link to that shared library. Thats how the identification on what kind of metadata is attached is implemented.

Comment: @Florian Z, Thanks for the update. It will be very helpful for me if you could provide the steps on how do I can created the shared library and how do I can link it with my plugin code while compile the custom plugin source code in order to access the shared library

Comment: struggling while doing these steps

Comment: It should be analogue to how you created your plugin - which should be a shared library as well..

Comment: yes, my plugin is also a shared library which I will copy to /usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/ folder

Comment: please have a look my Makefile added in the question section.  I successfully created the .so file but when I am trying to include it in the plugin file the compile is giving the error shown below.   gstcustom.cpp:48:10: fatal error: my-example-meta.h: No such file or directory
 #include "my-example-meta.h"

Comment: my meta data code is exactly same as mentioned in the below gstreamer link.

Comment: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugin-development/advanced/allocation.html?gi-language=c#implementing-new-gstmeta

Comment: @FlorianZwoch thnaks your input. some how i made it work

Comment: @FlorianZ Just wants one input from you. Currently, we are sending the meta data by integrating it to the GstVideoFrame. is there any possibility in Gstreamer to send only the metadata across the custom element without the video frame?

Comment: `GstMeta` is attached to a `GstBuffer`s. Their point is to add data to existing data. You don't need to fill the `GstBuffer`s data of course. But then, why not send your data in a regular buffer? You can send basically anything with them..

Comment: could you please share any reference link how do I can share a regular buffer across the custom elements?  basically I just wanted to send the meta data (generated by element a ) from custom element a to element b

Comment: for better understanding please see this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63638535/custom-gstreamer-plugin-to-support-multiple-2-source-pad

Comment: In the above link you can consider scalar as a 'A' element and custom-plugin as a 'B' element. So I wanted to pass only the meta data from A to B and B element will get the videoframe from the decoder plugin via a tee element.

Comment: It would be very helpful for me if you can provide some input on how do I can pass only meta data to the 'B' element instead of passing the meta data as a part of GstVideoFrame.  any reference link  or high level steps to do the same would be very much  helpful for me. thank you in advance

Comment: You can invent custom `caps`. These are just strings so that elements know that is in a `GstBuffer`s payload. Even if you leave these untouched you can transmit anything in a `GstBuffer`s payload. As long as both elemnts know what to di with that data.. there is really not much too it..

Comment: I am getting your points. let me try. I will come back to you if I have any doubt. thanks for your valuable inputs.

Comment: @Florian Zwoch Below is my sink element pad for the element 'A':  - Needs to change it for GstMeta buffer instead of VideoFrame 

  gst_element_class_add_pad_template (GST_ELEMENT_CLASS(klass),
    gst_pad_template_new ("sink", GST_PAD_SINK, GST_PAD_ALWAYS,
    gst_caps_from_string (VIDEO_SINK_CAPS ", width = (int) [1, 420], height = (int) [1, 420]")));

Comment: Below is my src pad for the element 'B' = Needs to change it for receving the GstMeta data instead of video frame:

    gst_element_class_add_pad_template (GST_ELEMENT_CLASS(klass),
    gst_pad_template_new ("src", GST_PAD_SRC, GST_PAD_ALWAYS,
    gst_caps_from_string (VIDEO_SRC_CAPS ",width = (int) [1, 420], height = (int) [1, 420]")));

Comment: Could you please help me on how do I can invent new cap over here and what type of cap I should use?  very new to this environment your support will be very appreciated